# tracking facebook like counts for many facebook pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, google-docs

Scenario: 
I'm looking to track the "like counts" for 100's to 1,000's of facebook pages.  Currently I have a google spreadsheet that is setup with graph api that [this post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10759917/tracking-competitors-facebook-likes) mentions.

I'm looking to automate the process a bit more if possible.

Here are my current steps:

1. find the fb business page address https://facebook.com/businessnamehere
2. locate the fb page id and enter it in the worksheet
3. the # of fans is populated for businesses that allow access through graph api

Couple Issues:

1. **Some business pages block access to the basic info and the following error is given:**

   `{
      "error": {
         "message": "Unsupported get request.",
         "type": "GraphMethodException",
         "code": 100
      }
   }`

   Is there any other way to pull the "like count" besides pulling up the actual fb business page and viewing the "like count"?
2. **The worksheet only pulls from the Page ID.**

   Is there any way to pull the "like count" from the facebook url only without needing to gather the fb page id?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use the username or businessname used after 'facebook.com/' on Graph api to retrieve the Page's likes

Comment: Thanks Anvesh.  I understand how to locate the page likes using the graph api.  I was looking for answers to my 2 Issues listed in the post.

Comment: Could you provide a example of Facebook page with your first problem?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/SouthCoastWinery

Comment: There are pages which might have geographical restrictions or age restrictions or even be locked viewable only to administrator, maybe this is the root cause of your problem (Stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) in introduction). Can you view the page as yourself or publicly?

Comment: the page referenced is available publicly.

Comment: This page has Geographical restriction as I can't open it. Instead Facebook just redirects me to my 'Home' . But someone in US can access the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are pages which might have geographical restrictions or age restrictions or even be locked viewable only to administrator, maybe this is the root cause of your problem (Stated here in [introduction](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)).

As for your second question, you can do graph request with the name on the business listed after "facebook.com/". For example you can find likes on [facebook.com/ign](https://www.facebook.com/ign) using

```
$info = $facebook->api('/ign','GET'); 
$likes = $info['likes'];
```

instead of using page ID as

```
$info = $facebook->api('/59685491632','GET'); 
$likes = $info['likes'];
```

where 59685491632 is IGN's page ID.